# Reference - App_Start namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, reference, nuget-package

I have this kind off problem with App_Start namespace

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'App_Start' does not exist in the namespace 'AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC D:\Code\CSharp\AqiCorp.FastSlot.V2\AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs    9   Active

But I have this folder in my project with all files inside.

Screen below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuEfi.png)

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The files in the `App_Start` folder probably exist in the `AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC` namespace. In C#, a folder does not necessarily represent a namespace. What's important is the `namespace` in the actual class files:

```
namespace AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instead you should simply refer to the `AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC` namespace, but since the `Startup` class is in the same namespace, you can simply remove the `using` statement for `AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC.App_Start`.

Comment: And what should I do to set this references?

Comment: Is that mean that should I replace "using AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC.App_Start"  on "using AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC"

Comment: @user3887572 Just remove `using AqiCorp.FastSlot.UI.MVC.App_Start;`

Comment: I did it and 2 errors gone but still I have missing namespaces in additional errors below. Do you know maybe what should I do with this errors too?

Comment: @user3887572 Have you read the error message and tried yourself?

Comment: Yes but I do not know process how search for missing directive or missing or assembly reference :(